# Using Boost.Serialization to parse a custom XML format

Tags: c++, xml-serialization, boost-serialization

I have a custom XML format that needs to be serialized to objects.
I only need to serialize certain tags and ignore the rest.
I have the impression that I need to write my own archive class but there is no documentation that explains how can it be done.
I do not need to save anything, just load the initial state of the object.
Anyone got a pointer for me?